How to fix tight kitchen drawers?
I recently moved into a new apartment and one of the kitchen drawers is quite tight, and needs a lot of force to be pulled out. I took a look at the slides and it looks like the rollers on either side of the cabinet are too close together, rubbing against the slide on the drawer and causing friction.
The black residue on the slide is from friction against the plastic bearing. Seems like it only rubs on this side, but the measurements don't look any different than the 3 drawers below it (which work fine). Any thoughts about how I can fix this?
I'm relatively handy, but am averse to making big changes (like changing the slides entirely) since I'm renting. So far, I'm considering either filing the bearings down, or maybe using some kind of lubricant (Superlube).


Kitchens almost certainly have multiple drawers. Try swapping the drawers around. It's quite possible the problem is a result of the previous tenant having accidentally or intentionally swapped a couple drawers.
In this instance, you don't own the cabinet or drawers so - they aren't yours to repair in a permanent way.  The tolerance on drawer slides is tight, something like -0/ +1/16. Notice the -0 and unfortunately that's your situation.  If the drawer were 1/16" to small, you could simply add a spacer under the screws that hold the slide to the drawer.  When you vacate, you can again advise the landlord and if necessary, remove your spacer.

The traditional lubricant for drawers is wax. Try just rubbing a candle on the area that you think is experiencing friction and see if that helps.
If you want to go high-tech, you can apply Teflon tape instead, which does the same thing more permanently.
I would not do anything more permanent without getting explicit permission from the owner. Certainly not mucking with the bearings or replacing the slides.

Something has gone wrong, maybe the cabinet has gotten wet and is swolen.
But "no big changes"
The smallest change would be to make the drawer body narrower.
Step one is cover your ass.  tell the land lord and ask them to fix it.
if nothing happens from that, and the drawer later falls apart while you're yanking on it... this is suddenly not your problem.
